# Yahoo cricket api throwing error 'No definition found for Table cricket.scorecard.live' ,any way to resolve it?

Tags: yql

I was trying to access the yahoo cricket api to get the latest live score ,news and commentry  but getting following issue

'No definition found for Table cricket.scorecard.live'

Can someone help me here?

or yahoo provide any commercial package?

Thanks in advance for helping!!

Comment: anyone can help here?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like yahoo has stopped the supports / api for cricket live scores.